# How does git compare files?

Tags: git, merge, word-diff

I'm using git with my latex files. I had few conflicts and because paragraphs are long, it's difficult to find what's the difference, so I'm curious how git compares files? Is there a way to turn on comparison char by char, if exists? For latex it would be great :) I don't like to write each sentence in new line, which is possible in latex and doesn't break the whole paragraph, but it's ugly.

When we have:

```
It's realy simple sentenec
```

and when Person#1 change it to:

```
It's a really simple sentenec
```

and simultaneously Person#2 change it to:

```
It's a really simple sentence.
```

There is a conflict and it should be resolved, because these changes are, or could be disjoint. Right?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587626/git-merging-within-a-line http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20021/merge-that-works-at-word-granularity-instead-of-line

Answer (score 1):

Git compare line by line.

If you want to compare char by char, you can do this command:

```
git diff --word-diff-regex=.
```