# Git merge: Keep certain lines in local file

Tags: git, git-merge

We configure our app version in multiple Maven pom.xml files as:

```
<version>8.1.0.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

This is always a pain to handle when merging as you will always have conflicts which require manual merging.  Can you configure Git to always keep the local copy of the `<version>...</version>` line when doing a merge?

Note we don't want to simply ignore all remote changes to the pom.xml files as there could have been non `<version>` changes we want to merge in.  We only want to ignore changes to the `<version>` tag.

**Note:** It has been mentioned that [Can git ignore a specific line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557467/can-git-ignore-a-specific-line) is a possible duplicate.  I don't see any mention of merging in that question.  Would appreciate someone describing how that translates to merging.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can git ignore a specific line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557467/can-git-ignore-a-specific-line)

Comment: What about this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587626/git-merging-within-a-line.  Particularly the second answer with the merge and smudge pieces

Comment: @Marcus the question might not _mention_ merging but the procédé is implicitly a merge (treating local changes in the face of incoming revisions). I think the duplicate is spot on, really.

Comment: Sorry what does procédé mean? :) I'd love it if someone could spell it out as an answer here.   I'm guessing others are looking for a clear statement of the solution as the question has a couple up votes.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a repository enabled with `git config rerere.enabled=true` then it will remember the resolutions you have done and re-apply them next time you have to do them. You can also apply this for all repositories with `git config --global rerere.enabled=true`

Comment: Can you configure rerere to only operate on a particular file pattern?  Ie: pom.xml