# How to merge changes within a line with Git?

Tags: git, merge, diff

Assume the following situation:

1. Create a file with contents `Hello World!`, add it, commit.
2. Change it to `Hi World!` in one branch, and to `Hello World` in another branch.
3. Now merging them will result in a conflict, because both changes are on the same line.

Consider the alternative where we separate the changes on different lines:
1. Create a file with contents `Hello\nWorld\n!`. (I'm denoting a line break by `\n`.)
2. Apply the analogous changes as before.
3. Now suddenly merging will work.

But a line break is a character like any other. Why does merging treat it so special?

More importantly, **are there git-compatible merge tools that will merge my first example without conflicts**, i.e. is it possible to merge changes within a line?

Comment: I don't understand why this was migrated to stackoverflow. It's about using a tool, not about programming. Also, a helpful comment was deleted in the process.

Comment: A similar question asking for word-by-word merge is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587626/git-merging-within-a-line

Answer (score -1):

All (standard) merge-tools in all VCSes are line-based (just because `diff`, `patch` under the hood are line based and **line of text is atom**, nor bigger nor smaller objects are even evaluated)… and I'll try don't mention "context" and "unifed" formats of diff and related "hunks" headache

Common answer for your question - "No, there are not such mergers (at least well-known and from reputable sources) in wild Net now. But - you can write it and use as special custom merge-tool in Git"

PS - Smudge|Clean filters approach from linked answer seems as a more promising (at least for me) solution