# Unable to apply git attribute filter

Tags: git, perl

## Problem

I am trying to apply the solution seen in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7781031/4843013). I have also tried to get [this solution to the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5588565/4843013) to work, but I've been unsuccessful in both cases. Both of these use clean/smudge attribute filters.

The goal is to improve Git's ability to process the files it is to be handling (LaTeX).

## What I've done

The short answer "what have you done" is "what the solutions said to do," however in case I've over looked something I'll go into detail.

One potential problem I've looked into is the possiblity that the answers are outdated. From looking at [Git Attributes Documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) the only thing I can think that might be out-dated is the location for the configuration file. For this reason I have both a `.gitattributes` file in the repo's root as well as a `.git/info/attributes` file. I have also tried with only one of these.

#### [Word-by-word](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5588565/4843013)

While not the solution I hope to get working, I figured I should try more than one in hopes of better identifying what is going wrong. I choose to go over this one, since I can at least get the script to work outside of Git.

In my config file I have

```
 [filter "wordbyword"]
    clean = /home/nero/myScripts/wordbyword.clean
    smudge = /home/nero/myScripts/wordbyword.smudge
```

I copy and paste the above locations into terminal with `vim` in front (so you know that I didn't make a typo there) and paste the contents below. First `clean` then `smudge` though for the latter to be of use, the former must work. . .which is the problem.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>)
{
    print "$_\n" foreach (m/(.*?\s+)/go);
    print '#@#DELIM#@#' . "\n";
}
```

and

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>)
{
    chomp; '#@#DELIM#@#' eq $_ and print "\n" or print;
}
```

The attributes file is simply `*.tex filter=wordbyword`

However when I run `git show HEAD:file.tex` it shows that it is being stored normally.

I know that the script works. When I run `perl wordbyword.clean test.tex` the output is as expected.

After poking around, I saw that I in fact DID have two files telling Git what needs to be done with .tex files. I had put one in a global location. Oops. This one works now. . .and the next one as well. At least for the cleaning. I'm going to check out smudging now before I answer my own question.

#### [Sentence by Sentance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7781031/4843013).

This is the one I prefer. To me it seems most reasonable to store a file in logical units. A paragraph is a logical unit, but its too large to be handled effective. A sentence is the next size of logical unit, and is about right.

This is actually the simpler one, since instead of a script, it is a simple one-line perl substitution.

```
[filter "sentencebreak"]
    clean = perl -pe \"s/[.]*?(\\?|\\!|\\.|'') /$&%NL%\\n/g unless m/%/||m/^[\\ *\\\\\\]/\"
    smudge = perl -pe \"s/%NL%\\n//gm\"
```

with the attributes `*.tex filter=sentencebreak`

However, when I run the substitution with `perl -pe "that long line" < test.tex` instead of printing newlines at every period, it prints `\n` at every white space (and leaves periods alone). I identified `\\n` which appears to be escaping the newline. Changing that to `\n` causes it to produce newlines, however it is still breaking at white space, which is not what I desire.

Looking closer at that perl substitution (I'm bad at perl) I see that its escaping the punctuation. Removing the extra `\` "mixed" that part of it.

Comment: `*.tex filter=wordbyword` (**k** => **d**).

Comment: I'm assuming that is a terse explaination of what I need to do, but I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "(k=>d)".

Comment: Oh! I see. A typo. I'll fix that and see if it works. I'll also check the other one (the one I actually want) for that sort of thing too. Thanks. That did not fix the problem. It is still doing nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel quite silly. It was pointed out that there was a spelling mistake. In the process of correcting this mistake I came to see that I had forgotten about the global attributes file at /home/nero/.config/.git/attributes.

Both items are working as expected now.

To be clear, the issue was too many configuration files saying the same thing was confusing Git.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know